# msgraph-sdk-php v2 how to pass skiptoken to request?

Tags: php, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

im trying to get more users than 100 (default limit). Unfortunately, documentation is pretty simple (lot of stuff i search in sources of sdk)
But i have no clue how to pass nextLink argument skiptoken. In v1 of SDK i just expand url in GET i suppose, but i would like to use v2 of SDK. I saw nextLink in delta-query (but this is something else).

i try this, but its not working.

```
$nextlink = str_replace('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$skiptoken=','',$response->getOdataNextLink());
$request = new UsersRequestBuilderGetRequestConfiguration();
$request->queryParameters = UsersRequestBuilderGetRequestConfiguration::createQueryParameters();
$request->queryParameters->expand = array('skiptoken' => $nextLink);
$response = $o365->users()->get($request)->wait();
```

i also try, i know there is no skiptoken param

```
$request = new UsersRequestBuilderGetRequestConfiguration();
$request->queryParameters = UsersRequestBuilderGetRequestConfiguration::createQueryParameters();
$request->queryParameters->skiptoken = $nextLink;
$response = $o365->users()->get($request)->wait();
```

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In v2 SDK, there should be `PageIterator` for paging through a collection

```
$users = $graphServiceClient->users()->get()->wait();

$pageIterator = new PageIterator($users, $graphServiceClient->getRequestAdapter());

$counter = 0;
$callback = function Microsoft\Graph\Generated\Models\User $user) use (&$counter) {
    echo "Id: {$user->getId()}\n";
    $counter ++;
    return ($counter % 5 != 0);
};

while ($pageIterator->hasNext()) {
    // iteration pauses and resumes after every 5 users
    $pageIterator->iterate($callback);

    echo "\nPaused iteration...Total users: {$counter}\n\n";
}
```

[Paging through a collection](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php/blob/058db2fd23649772a823f75f2e3567febe7f3b2a/docs/Examples.md#paging-through-a-collection)